How do I work around parameter contravariance when declaring callbacks on generic classess?
I'm trying to write a generic class called MultiConfigWidget where T extends Config, and in that generic class, have a callback that serves as a builder with the signature Widget Function(BuildContext, T).
class MultiConfigWidget<T extends Config> extends StatelessWidget {
  // ...
  final T config;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) builder;
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) => builder(context, config)
}

Assume DerivedConfig extends Config. When I try to use my class in the following way, I get a type error:
MultiConfigWidget<DerivedConfig>(
  builder: (BuildContext context, DerivedConfig config) => 
    SomeConfigurableWidget( // Expects config to be DerivedConfig
      config: config,
    ),
),

If I change the signature of builder to Widget Function(BuildContext, Config), it fixes the runtime error, but SomeConfigurableWidget needs config to be of type DerivedConfig.
I'm aware that the type error is because the argument to builder expects a subtype of Widget Function(Config), and Widget Function(DerivedConfig) is NOT a subtype since parameters are contravariant.
But, to my reasoning, an instance of MultiConfigWidget is guaranteed to execute the builder callback with an argument of type T, NOT with the base type. Since it's never going to execute builder(context, instanceOfBaseType), and is only ever going to execute builder(context, instanceOfT), I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting the error at runtime.
How can I initialize builder with a function that takes T as a parameter, and calls it with the runtime type of T, instead of the base type from the generic?
Edit: I can work around this issue with something like:
class MultiConfigWidget<T extends Config> extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, Config) builder;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) => builder(context, config)
}

MultiConfigWidget<DerivedConfig>(
  builder: (context, config) => 
    SomeConfigurableWidget( // Expects config to be DerivedConfig
      config: config as DerivedConfig,
    ),
),


Which gives me no type errors, and no runtime errors. Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to a cast?
